# Calling a function expecting parent class type with subtype argument

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-2

I have started migrating my code from Dart 1.24 to Dart 2.1.0 and I am having some issues with some type casting in functions right now.

I have the following code, which is basically a login page on which I register the enter key and the mouse click on a button to call a function:

```
querySelector('#btnLgn').onClick.listen(onClickLogin);
querySelector('#usrName').onKeyUp.listen(onKeyboardPressed);

void onKeyboardPressed(KeyboardEvent e) {
    if (e.keyCode == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        onClickLogin(e);
    }
}

Future onClickLogin(Event e) async {
    [...]
}
```

The `onClick` listener should call the function with a `MouseEvent` while `onKeyUp` is a `KeyboardEvent` both of which are subtypes of the `UIEvent` class which is a subtype of `Event`.

Whenever `onClickLogin` is called I am getting the following error whether I click on the button or press enter:

```
_js_helper.TypeErrorImpl.new {message: "Type 'Event$' is not a subtype of ?expected type 'KeyboardEvent$'.", Symbol(_error): Error at Object.dart.throw (http://localhost:32400/packages/$sdk/dev_compiler/amd/dart_sdk.js:48…}
```

Why is it that I cannot call `onClickLogin` with a subtype of `Event` or `UIEvent` while expecting one of those 2 classes?

Comment: The question is backwards - Based on the error this is "Calling a function expecting a subtype argument with parent class type".  The function expects a `KeyboardEvent` and it's getting the parent type `Event` - this looks like it's happening with `onKeyboardPressed` not `onClickLogin`. That said I don't know why you'd be getting an `Event` instead of a `KeyboardEvent` since `onKeyUp` should be a `Stream<KeyboardEvent>`...

Comment: After some further testing, you are definitely right. It seems the ```onKeyUp``` event is called from the browser auto-complete feature and definitely passes an ```Event``` instead of ```KeyboardEvent```. Thanks